# Variable that holds value of class pointer object?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to make a variable that will hold class pointer objects.

Here are two of my class pointer objects with constructor values.

```
Goblin *g = new Goblin(6, 6, 3, 8, 2,1);
Barbarian *b = new Barbarian(6, 6, 0, 12, 2, 2);
```

I want to create a variable that will hold data like this so I can have a player choose what creature he wants to be and the variable will hold that data so I can use it for my function.

Here is the header of the function I want to use.

```
void battle(Creature *a, Creature *d, std::string nameA, std::string nameD);
```

here is the function being called in main()

```
battle(g, b, playerName, opponentCreature);
```

The values g, and b, are what I want to replace with my new variable.
I tried using string and int variable types but that wasn't working. Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Right now, you have a `Goblin` and a `Barbarian` doing battle, what do you want to happen?

Comment: I want a variable that can hold the Goblin or Barbarian values and soon more creatures, and which creature gets assigned to that variable will depend on what the user chooses. That way when the battle function is called instead of only goblin or barbarian fighting it will be based on what the user chose in a menu selection I didn't post.

Comment: Sounds like a job for derivation and virtual functions.

Comment: My class has virtual functions.

Comment: @CaseyBalza: What class? You haven't shown us any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by using these two lines.

```
Creature *personCode = 0;

Creature *opponentCode = 0;
```

Here is how they are tied into my program.

```
std::cout << "Choose your creature." << std::endl;

std::cout << "\n1). Goblin." << std::endl;
std::cout << "2). Barbarian." << std::endl;

std::cin >> choice;
std::cin.clear();//clear the input
std::cin.ignore(100, '\n');//ignore 100 char or up to new line.

switch (choice)
{
    case 1:// std::cout << "Goblin" << std::endl;
        playerCreature = "Goblin";
        personCode = new Goblin(6, 6, 3, 8, 2, 1);
        break;

    case 2:// std::cout << "Barbarian" << std::endl;
        playerCreature = "Barbarian";
        personCode = new Barbarian(6, 6, 0, 12, 2, 2);
        break;
}

std::cout << "Choose your opponent" << std::endl;

std::cout << "\n1). Goblin." << std::endl;
std::cout << "2). Barbarian." << std::endl;

std::cin >> choice;
std::cin.clear();//clear the input
std::cin.ignore(100, '\n');//ignore 100 char or up to new line.

switch (choice)
{
case 1: //std::cout << "Goblin" << std::endl;
    opponentCreature = "Goblin";
    opponentCode = new Goblin(6, 6, 3, 8, 2, 1);
    break;

case 2: //std::cout << "Barbarian" << std::endl;
    opponentCreature = "Barbarian";
    opponentCode = new Barbarian(6, 6, 0, 12, 2, 2);
    break;
}
```

And here is the function being called now.

```
battle(personCode, opponentCode, playerName, opponentCreature);
```